# How match paths with /lang? using the express middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want target paths that have `/lang?` in the path, but i just know how target the paths that start with the `/lang?`

I have two routes:

```
app.get('/lang?.....
app.get('/bottle/lang?.......
```

I want target this routes using the app.use('/something', myMiddleware);

How can i do that?

I search in the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use), and i just find the tutorial to target paths that START with something.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use a RegExp. Example:

```
app.all(/\/lang$/, function(req, res, next) {
  // do something
  console.log('matched a lang!');
  next();
});
```

Or you can use `app.use()`, except with a [slightly different regexp](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2535#issuecomment-73458868):

```
app.use(/^.*?\/lang$/, function(req, res, next) {
  // do something
  console.log('matched a lang!');
  next();
});
```

Comment: It should, but it appears to be a bug in Express since `app.all(/\/lang$/, ...);` works just fine.

Comment: i am sorry for asking.. but, what is the difference between app.all and app.use?

Comment: strange.. i cant use the app.all neither.. if i try, will break the site

Comment: IIRC `app.all()` adds a new layer to the router for *every* support HTTP method, whereas `app.use()` only adds *one* new layer to the router that matches *any* HTTP request (and the given route path). I cannot duplicate any "breaking" issues that you're alluding to.

Comment: Ok, so it appears that Express still has separate behaviors for handlers added via `.all()/.get()/.post()/etc` and those added via `.use()`. FWIW here is the relevant [issue I opened about it](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2535).